# what is the life span of permanent magnet and how does it reduces?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

what is the life span of a permanent magnet? if it is reduces, how is it reduced ? how much time to cause when the continuous pressure is applied to the permanent  magnets ?which type of permanent magnets have high life span when compared to other permanent magnets ?

Comment: Hi Santhu, Welcome to Physics SE. These are all interesting questions, unfortunately your post does not meet the standard of this website, and will be closed soon.Please take the tour

Comment: All capital nicks look bad, I suggest to change to a normal one (be simply "Santhu Nani").

Answer (score 1):

We have nickel neodymium magnets having magnetic field 0.5 T, This is fairly high magnetic field and require precautions when you work with them or you may loss your fingers (if you use large size magnets >0.5 inch dia). They are pretty stable. I have been using them for last one year and magnetic field reduces to .48 T which is not much. I think several of such magnets are pretty stable and the main reason for loss of magnetic field is heating.

The basic reason for the loss in magnetic field is the randomization of the magnetic zones and that is a property of material (I believe so).

This information is not very fundamental in nature but it is my practical first hand experience.

Regards,